# operator && cannot be applied to boolean,char

Tags: java

So I am working on a ModelViewController tic-tac-toe game homework and I am trying to check that if the board is empty at position xpos, ypos or not, but I got an error that says

> operator && cannot be applied to boolean,char

Why does this occur and how can I change it to make it work?

```
double xpos,ypos,xr,yr;
char[][] position = {{' ',' ',' '},
             {' ',' ',' '},
             {' ',' ',' '}};

public boolean isEmpty(int xpos, int ypos){
    int pos=xpos+3*ypos;
    boolean isPosWithinRange = pos>=0 && pos<9 ;
    return isPosWithinRange && position[xpos][ypos]=' ';
}
```

Comment: you're using assignment (=) instead of comparison (==)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

correct your code, to use == for comparison

```
return isPosWithinRange && position[xpos][ypos]==' ';
```

Comment: Thanks. I always got confused with = and ==.

Answer (score 1):

Use == when you are compare... '='  will assign the value it won't compare...